# How do I get the list of all broken-over-two-lines words in my document?

Tags: hyphenation

The question is quite simple. When I compile my latex document, the pdf will contain words that are broken over two lines (hyphenated).

Is there a way to know all the words that my compiler breaks in that particular document?
Maybe this can be an output of the compiler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get hyphenation output?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214824/how-to-get-hyphenation-output)

Comment: @egreg that question is really asking for all the possible hyphenation points, but this, I think, is asking for which ones are actually used, which is harder but deducible from `\tracingparagraphs=1` with some effort.

Comment: Is using LuaLaTeX an option for you? If it is, you should take a look at the [lua-check-hyphen](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/lua-check-hyphen) package. An excerpt from the package's README file: "[The package] lists all hyphenated words in the log file as well as in the file with the extension `.uhy`".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the reply. How can I do what you suggest?

Comment: @the_candyman it would be a lot simpler to do what Mico suggests. What I was suggesting was: If you put `\tracingparagraphs=1` into your document and look in the log there is in principle enough information to get the answer but it is mixed with information about breakpoints _not_ chosen so I see no automated way to do it, it requires reading the texbook (again) and scratching your head a lot (I just tried a simple three line paragraph:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks again, I will try this.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the reply. I will try this.